# Panels creation at runtime can't see them

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

My problem is i am trying to make a panel. My button in in Main.mxml whereas the panel functions are defined in panel_Create.mxml. the code works fine. In panel_Create their are functions to create panels at runtime. The problem i am facing is when i run the program it wont show the panels but it does increase the value of n and after 8 clicks it gives alert message. Please tell me why cant i see panels. The code works fine when i put all the code in Main.mxml

```
<fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[

                import Components.panel_Create;
                import mx.controls.Alert;
                import spark.components.Button
                public var adminPanel:panel_Create = new panel_Create();

                public var n:Number = 0;
                public function panel(event:MouseEvent): void
                {
                    if ( n < 8)
                    {
                        adminPanel.panel_Create(n);
                        n++;
                    }
                    else
                    Alert.show('More Panels Not Allowed', 'Alert Box', mx.controls.Alert.OK);          
                }
            ]]>
        </fx:Script>

        <s:Button id="add" includeIn="State1" x="398" y="10" label="Add Panel" click="panel(event)"/>
        <Components2:panel_Create includeIn="State1" x="10" y="66" width="737" height="599">
        </Components2:panel_Create>

    </s:Application>
```

Comment: I don't understand your logic on most of these.  Why are you creating a `panel_Create` class (which is a *horrid* naming convention) and then having that class handle the panel creation?  What are you exactly trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: i am trying to make a series of panels and some more things inside the panels at runtime. leave the names i will set them later. i want to do this in different mxml files not in same main.mxml. Here i click on button it should initiate a panel_create function in panel_create mxml. but the panels wont show up when i click on them

Comment: -1 - This question can not be answered without more details.  Specifically, some of the relevant sections of code from the `panel_Create` class must be provided, especially where ever the `addChild` method is being called.

Comment: var myPanel:Panel = new Panel();
    myPanel.id = xx;
    addElement(myPanel);
    setElementIndex(myPanel, index);
    index++; that is the code it should call

Comment: If you place your additional code back into the original question as an edit (rather than as a comment), I would gladly remove the -1.  Otherwise, the site rules prohibit me changing my vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adminPanel is not being created. you have to do `addElement(adminPanel)` itself

```
if ( n < 8)
                    {
                        adminPanel.panel_Create(n);
                        addElement(adminPanel)
                        n++;
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the 8 panels are created and based on the code in one of your comments **they are added as child elements to the adminPanel**.

The problem is that your adminPanel is never added to the stage so is not visible.

Comment: i am thinking the same now the problem is how can i make them visible

Comment: Take a look at this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7ff9.html Pay attention to addElement()

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private var panels:Array = [];

            private function addPanel():void
            {
                if (panels.length < 8)
                {
                    var panel:Panel = new Panel();
                    panel.title = "Panel "+(panels.length + 1);
                    panels.push(panel);
                    addElement(panel);
                }else{
                    trace('More Panels Not Allowed');
                }                   
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Button label="Add Panel" click="addPanel()"/>
</s:Application>
```